# How to do code coverage for a remote repository deployed in Jboss server using Emma?

Tags: testing, testng, code-coverage, emma, eclemma

Here is my scenario.

1. I have a code base, which is built and deployed as EAR on jBoss server.
2. I have a separate testing framework.
3. Now I want to run the classes of that EAR using my testing framework.
4. The test cases are written in TestNG.
5. Also I want to know the code coverage of the EAR.
6. I have used eclEmma to do code coverage for Junits, it was simple as the code and tests are at same place.
   How can I use Emma in the case of remote code base. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

EclEmma is Eclipse plugin based on [JaCoCo - Java Code Coverage Library](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/index.html). JaCoCo provides various ways for collection of code coverage. In particular you can attach it to the server as a Java agent and request information about coverage remotely. And even [import and show it in Eclipse using EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html).